# What is wrong with this xml parser (Android)?

Tags: android, xml, parsing, sax

I would like to parse an xml file. I am trying to locate the error, but i can not find it. Could you help me, pls?
xml:

```
<maintag>
    <data>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>x y</name>
        <age>16</age>
        <phone>06/30 123-4567</phone>
        <address>Veszprem Valami ut 10.</address>
    </data>
    <data>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>p q</name>
        <age>18</age>
        <phone>06/70 987-6543</phone>
        <address>Budapest Ulloi ut 21.</address>
    </data>
</maintag>
```

XMLParser class:

```
package com.example.xmlproba;

import java.util.jar.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
import android.util.Log;

public class XMLParser extends DefaultHandler {

    boolean xmlStartLine = false;
    boolean id = false;
    boolean data = false;
    boolean maintag = false;
    boolean age = false;
    boolean name = false;
    boolean phone = false;
    boolean address = false;

    Data currentData;
    DataContainer dataContainer;

    public XMLParser(DataContainer dataContainer){
        this.dataContainer=dataContainer;
        Log.d("FUNC","XMLPARSER()");

        // Data d = new Data();
    }

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

        Log.d("START","START");

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("MAINTAG")) {
            Log.d("Maintagfound","mtf");

        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("DATA")) {
            //create new data object 
            currentData = new Data();
            Log.d("NEWDATA","NEWDATA");
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("ID")) {
            id  = true;
            Log.d("id","id");
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("NAME")) {
            name = true;
            Log.d("name","name");
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("AGE")) {
            age = true;
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("PHONE")) {
            phone = true;
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("ADDRESS")) {
            address = true;
        } else {
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        Log.d("END","END");
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("DATA")) {
            //todo at the end of a data node
            //dataContainer.addDataToList(currentData);
            //dataContainer.dataList.add(currentData);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        Log.d("CHARS","CHARS");
        if (id) {
            String s = new String(ch, start, length);
            currentData.setId(Integer.parseInt(s));
            Log.d("IDIDID",s);
            id = false;
        } else if (name) {
            String s = new String(ch, start, length);
            Log.d("NAME1",s);
            currentData.setName(s);
            Log.d("NAME2",currentData.getName());
            name = false;
        } else if (age) {
            String s = new String(ch, start, length);
            currentData.setAge(Integer.parseInt(s));

            age = false;
        } else if (phone) {
            String s = new String(ch, start, length);
            currentData.setPhone(s);
            phone = false;
        } else if (address) {
            String s = new String(ch, start, length);
            currentData.setAdress(s);
            address = false;
        } else {
        }

    }

}
```

And the parsing part of my activity:

```
private void readXML() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("FUNC","READXML");
    try {

        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        XMLParser xp = new XMLParser(dataContainer);
        xr.setContentHandler(xp);
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(
                R.raw.data);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(is));

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("PARSERCONFEX","PARSERCONFEX");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("SAXEX","SAXEX");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("IOEX","IOEX");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

From the log.d() i can see that only the log from constructor, the "CHARS" and "END" logs are created.
Here is my log:

```
12-06 06:38:11.063: E/Trace(629): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-06 06:38:11.623: D/FUNC(629): INIT
12-06 06:38:11.623: D/FUNC(629): READXML
12-06 06:38:11.643: D/FUNC(629): XMLPARSER()
12-06 06:38:11.664: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.664: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.664: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.664: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.664: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.673: D/END(629): END
12-06 06:38:11.673: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.673: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.673: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.673: D/END(629): END
12-06 06:38:11.673: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.673: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.683: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.683: D/END(629): END
12-06 06:38:11.683: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.683: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.683: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.683: D/END(629): END
12-06 06:38:11.683: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.683: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.693: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.693: D/END(629): END
12-06 06:38:11.693: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.693: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.693: D/END(629): END
12-06 06:38:11.693: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.693: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.693: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.693: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.703: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.703: D/END(629): END
12-06 06:38:11.703: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.713: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.713: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.713: D/END(629): END
12-06 06:38:11.713: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.713: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.713: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.713: D/END(629): END
12-06 06:38:11.713: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.713: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.723: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.723: D/END(629): END
12-06 06:38:11.723: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.723: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.723: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.723: D/END(629): END
12-06 06:38:11.733: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.733: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.733: D/END(629): END
12-06 06:38:11.733: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.733: D/CHARS(629): CHARS
12-06 06:38:11.733: D/END(629): END
12-06 06:38:12.063: I/Choreographer(629): Skipped 77 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-06 06:38:12.093: D/gralloc_goldfish(629): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

Comment: *"I am trying to locate the error, but i can not find it."* We can't find it either without a stacktrace or proper description of what you consider to be erroneous.

Comment: The error is that it isnt create my object Data currentData. It isnt enter the if intersection where it should create the currentData instance. (and it isnt enter the intersection where it should be log that "Maintagfound").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that what you wanna do using SAX

### JAVA CLASSES

**Data**

```
public class Data {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private String phone;
    private String address;


    public Data(){}


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }


    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }


    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }


    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }


    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }


    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }


}
```

**DatasHandler**

```
public class DatasHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private ArrayList<Data> alDatas;
    private Data data;
    private String reading;

    public DatasHandler(){}

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

        if(qName.equals("maintag")){
            alDatas = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        if(qName.equals("data")){
            data = new Data();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {

        if(qName.equals("data")){
            alDatas.add(data);
            data = null;
        }
        if(qName.equals("id")){
            data.setId(Integer.parseInt(reading));
        }
        if(qName.equals("name")){
            data.setName(reading);
        }
        if(qName.equals("age")){
            data.setAge(Integer.parseInt(reading));
        }
        if(qName.equals("phone")){
            data.setPhone(reading);
        }
        if(qName.equals("address")){
            data.setAddress(reading);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        reading = new String(ch, start, length);
    }

    public ArrayList<Data> getAlDatas() {
        return alDatas;
    }


}
```

**XMLManager**

```
public final class XMLManager {

    public static ArrayList<Data> getAlDatas(){
        ArrayList<Data> alDatas = null;
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
            DatasHandler dHandler = new DatasHandler();
            parser.parse(new File("D:\\Loic_Workspace\\SaxExample\\res\\test.xml"), dHandler);
            alDatas = dHandler.getAlDatas();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return alDatas;
    }


}
```

**Main**

```
public class MyMain {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Data> alDatas = XMLManager.getAlDatas();

        for(Data d:alDatas){
            System.out.println(d.getName());
            System.out.println(d.getId());
            System.out.println(d.getAge());
            System.out.println(d.getPhone());
            System.out.println(d.getAddress());
            System.out.println("--------------------");
        }

    }

}
```

### Console output

```
x y
1
16
06/30 123-4567
Veszprem Valami ut 10.
--------------------
p q
2
18
06/70 987-6543
Budapest Ulloi ut 21.
--------------------
```

You seem want to use it on Android. So I think that you can do the following in XMLManager class :

```
InputSource in = new InputSource(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data));
parser.parse(in, dHandler);
```

Tell me if it works,